# Why can't I spread in an array inside an object that has another object at the same level being filtered

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

The below is a dummy reproduction of a part of an app I am writing.

I am `mapping` an array of data using `const test` that return days of the week. Once I click on a certain day, and this certain day is not present in `this.state.testingDates.array` i use `setState` to add this day of the week into `this.state.testingDates.array`.

When I click on a certain day I get the following error `Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance`.

Why can't I spread `...array`, so I preserve the old `state` with my `state` organized in this way, having `array: []` at the same level than `classFrequency`?

If I move `array` one level up(ending with `this.state.array`, it all works smoothly.

Here is my [code](https://codesandbox.io/embed/understanding-non-iterable-error-on-my-app-state-9jjd9?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    testingDates: {
      array: [],
      classFrequency: [
        { day: "Sun", DayOfWeek: 0, toggleClassColor: "inherit" },
        { day: "Mon", DayOfWeek: 1, toggleClassColor: "inherit" },
        { day: "Tue", DayOfWeek: 2, toggleClassColor: "inherit" },
        { day: "Wed", DayOfWeek: 3, toggleClassColor: "inherit" },
        { day: "Thu", DayOfWeek: 4, toggleClassColor: "inherit" },
        { day: "Fri", DayOfWeek: 5, toggleClassColor: "inherit" },
        { day: "Sat", DayOfWeek: 6, toggleClassColor: "inherit" }
      ]
    }
  };

  nonIterableHandler = (childDay, childIndex) => {
    const classFrequency = this.state.testingDates.classFrequency;
    if (!this.state.testingDates.array.includes(childDay.day)) {
      this.setState(
        ({ array }) => ({
          array: [...array, classFrequency[childIndex].day]
        }),
        () => {
          console.log("array spreads...", this.state.array);
        }
      );
    }
  };

  render() {
    let test = this.state.testingDates.classFrequency.map((val, index) => (
      <p
        key={val.day}
        style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
        onClick={() => this.nonIterableHandler(val, index)}
      >
        {val.day}
      </p>
    ));

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>testing non-iterable</h1>
        {test}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Just linking this here: [How to update nested state properties in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43040721/how-to-update-nested-state-properties-in-react)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial state does not have an `array` property at the top level:

```
  state = {
    testingDates: {
      array: [],
      // ...
    }
  }
```

The array is inside the `testingDates` object. So if you do

```
this.setState(
  ({ array }) =>
```

it won't work, because no `array` property exists at the top.

You can properly extract the array using nested destructuring if you want:

```
this.setState(
  ({ testingDates: { array }}) =>
```

And make sure to assign the new array to the proper nested property:

```
this.setState(
  ({ testingDates: { array, ...restTesting }, ...restTop }) => ({
    testingDates: {
      array: [...array, classFrequency[childIndex].day],
      ...restTesting
    },
    ...restTop
  }),
  () => {
    console.log("array spreads...", this.state.testingDates.array);
  }
);
```

Comment: Oh I see! You mean top by saying that there is no ```object``` called ```array``` at the top level of ```state```? Interesting... I am still picking the syntax

Comment: alright, and what If ```testingDates``` is one level deeper into ```state```?

Comment: You could do the same sort of thing: `({ testingDates: { nested: { array, ...restNested } ...restTesting }, ...restTop })` Or, at that point, it'd probably be better to use only a single level of destructuring and list the properties that need to be spread via dot notation

Comment: oh I see. So lets say that ```testingDates``` is now inside ```newClassForm```, making ```this.state.newClassForm.testingDates.array```. I see what you say. So I guess this would be a clean solution, wright? ```this.setState(
        ({ newClassForm: { testingDates } }) => ({
          array: [...testingDates.array, classFrequency[childIndex].day]
        }),
        () => {
          console.log("array spreads...", this.state.array);
        }
      );```

Comment: The object returned from the function should have the same structure as in the initial state, so it needs a `newClassForm` object. `({ ..restTop, newClassForm: ({ ...restClassForm, array: [...testingDates.array, classFrequency[childIndex].day] } })` Make sure to spread the rest of the properties in the state as well, else they'll be lost

Comment: Thanks for shedding some light. I did not manage to figure out our last comment's syntax.. This is what I came with: (next comment)

Comment: this.setState(
        ({
          newClassForm: {
            testingDates: { array, ...restTesting },
            ...restClassForm
          },
          ...restTop
        }) => ({
          newClassForm: {
            testingDates: {
              array: [...array, classFrequency[childIndex].day],
              ...restTesting
            },
            ...restClassForm
          },
          ...restTop
        }),
        () => {
          console.log(
            "array spreads",
            this.state.newClassForm.testingDates.array
          );
        }
      );

Comment: on your last comment It seemed that you managed to keep the state structure shorter once you use ```setState``` and I did not manage to use ```...restTop``` at the beginning. How would it be possible to shorten my solution above into a slicker syntax? If so, could you please share with me the whole deal?